# Loading Distance package not responding in Julia

Tags: julia, julia-studio

In Julia Studio 0.4.4 on Mac OS X 10.9, I am unable to load the `Distance` package. 
When I run:

```
julia> using Distance
```

Julia studio terminal do not respond, it never goes back to the prompt. I have tried to reinstall the package as well as to remove the `~/.julia folder`, but the problem persists.

```
julia> Pkg.status()
Required packages:
 - DataFrames                    0.4.3
 - Distance                      0.2.6
 - IJulia                        0.1.11             55b60c47 (dirty)
 - RDatasets                     0.1.1
Additional packages:
 - BinDeps                       0.2.12
 - Blocks                        0.0.4
 - DataArrays                    0.0.3
 - GZip                          0.2.12
 - Homebrew                      0.0.6
 - JSON                          0.3.5
 - Nettle                        0.1.3
 - NumericExtensions             0.3.6
 - REPLCompletions               0.0.1
 - SortingAlgorithms             0.0.1
 - StatsBase                     0.3.8
 - URIParser                     0.0.2
 - ZMQ                           0.1.11
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: what do you mean by "do not respond"? The expected behavior of loading a package is make all of it's exports available and then just put you back at the prompt. What happens when you type `Distance` at the prompt after doing `using Distance`?

Comment: The problem is that it never gets back to the prompt. With other packages, for me it works as expected.

Comment: huh, that is very odd, I've never heard of a package doing that. I would first try deleting your `~/.julia` and reinstalling your packages, and then if that doesn't fix it file an issue on the Distance.jl repo: https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distance.jl/issues

Comment: Thanks James for your help. I have tried to reinstall the package as well as to remove the `~/.julia` folder but the problem persists. I have just filed the issue.

Comment: Doubt this is still a problem for you but https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distance.jl says Distance is deprecated, use https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distances.jl instead